# how to get a variable get selected bydefault in YUI Query Builder?

Tags: yui, query-builder

I am using YUI query builder.i want an option selected by default when i load page.

How can i do it?

Comment: You should post your question on the Gallery module's forum so the author can answer you himself http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=138